# React Native - Print HTML directly to printer without OS print dialog

Tags: react-native, mobile, sdk, thermal-printer

I'm currently working on a React Native application where I need to print HTML content directly to a printer without displaying the OS print dialog. I am using react-native-print to print, and it works well, but it still opens the print dialog which I would like to avoid.

My application is already connected to a Brother printer, and I've tried using the react-native-brother-printer library, but I wasn't able to achieve the desired functionality.

```
// ... existing imports ...
import RNPrint from 'react-native-print';

// ... existing code ...

const confirmAndPrint = () => {
    const requestBody: CreateVisitorDTO = {
        name,
        email,
        phone,
        organization,
        image,
    };
    const html = prepareHTML();
    axios
        .put('/Visit', requestBody)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            RNPrint.print({ html });
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};

// ... existing code ...
```

In the `confirmAndPrint` function, I prepare the HTML and send a request to my backend. After that, I use `RNPrint.print` to print the HTML. However, this opens the printer dialog.

I'm considering converting my HTML to an image before printing, but I'm not sure if this will solve my problem.

Can anyone suggest libraries or techniques that I can use to print directly from my React Native app to the printer without displaying the print dialog?

I expect it to after i push the confirm and print, it will automatically send label with specified size and text to printer and print it out. No pop up windows. Just print and back to home screen where next person can register their attendance and get a name tag printed out.